# ReadDirectoryChangesW Error in WIN32 API project?

Tags: c++, c, winapi, readdirectorychangesw

```
void TestDirChanges(LPCWSTR path)
{
/*
FileName member of FILE_NOTIFY_INFORMATION has only one WCHAR according to definition. Most likely, this field will have more characters. 
So the expected size of one item is (sizeof(FILE_NOTIFY_INFORMATION) + MAX_PATH * sizeof(WCHAR)).
Prepare buffer for 256 items.
*/
char buf[256 * (sizeof(FILE_NOTIFY_INFORMATION) + MAX_PATH * sizeof(WCHAR))] = {0};
DWORD bytesReturned = 0;
BOOL result = FALSE;
FILE_NOTIFY_INFORMATION *fni = NULL;

HANDLE hDir = CreateFile(path,
    FILE_LIST_DIRECTORY | STANDARD_RIGHTS_READ,
    FILE_SHARE_READ | FILE_SHARE_WRITE | FILE_SHARE_DELETE,
    NULL,
    OPEN_EXISTING,
    FILE_FLAG_BACKUP_SEMANTICS,
    NULL);

if (!hDir || hDir == INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE)
{
    wprintf(L"CreateFile failed\n");
    return;
}

while (1)
{
    result = ReadDirectoryChangesW(hDir,
        buf,
        sizeof(buf) / sizeof(*buf),
        TRUE, /* monitor the entire subtree */
        FILE_NOTIFY_CHANGE_FILE_NAME |
            FILE_NOTIFY_CHANGE_DIR_NAME |
            FILE_NOTIFY_CHANGE_ATTRIBUTES |
            FILE_NOTIFY_CHANGE_SIZE | 
            FILE_NOTIFY_CHANGE_LAST_WRITE | 
            FILE_NOTIFY_CHANGE_LAST_ACCESS |
            FILE_NOTIFY_CHANGE_CREATION |
            FILE_NOTIFY_CHANGE_SECURITY,
        &bytesReturned,
        NULL,
        NULL);

    if (result && bytesReturned)
    {
        wchar_t filename[MAX_PATH];
        wchar_t action[256];
        for (fni = (FILE_NOTIFY_INFORMATION*)buf; fni; )
        {
            switch (fni->Action)
            {
            case FILE_ACTION_ADDED:
                wcscpy_s(action, sizeof(action) / sizeof(*action), L"File added:");
                break;

            case FILE_ACTION_REMOVED:
                wcscpy_s(action, sizeof(action) / sizeof(*action), L"File removed:");
                break;

            case FILE_ACTION_MODIFIED:
                wcscpy_s(action, sizeof(action) / sizeof(*action), L"File modified:");
                break;

            case FILE_ACTION_RENAMED_OLD_NAME:
                wcscpy_s(action, sizeof(action) / sizeof(*action), L"File renamed, was:");
                break;

            case FILE_ACTION_RENAMED_NEW_NAME:
                wcscpy_s(action, sizeof(action) / sizeof(*action), L"File renamed, now is:");
                break;

            default:
                swprintf_s(action, sizeof(action) / sizeof(*action), L"Unkonwn action: %ld. File name is:", fni->Action);
            }

            if (fni->FileNameLength)
            {
                wcsncpy_s(filename, MAX_PATH, fni->FileName, fni->FileNameLength / 2);
                filename[fni->FileNameLength / 2] = 0;
                wprintf(L"%s '%s'\n", action, filename);
            }
            else
            {
                wprintf(L"%s <EMPTY>\n", action);
            }                

            if (fni->NextEntryOffset)
            {
                char *p = (char*)fni;
                fni = (FILE_NOTIFY_INFORMATION*)(p + fni->NextEntryOffset);
            }
            else
            {
                fni = NULL;
            }
        }
    }
    else
    {
        wprintf(L"ReadDirectoryChangesW failed\n");
    }
}

CloseHandle(hDir);
}
```

My code runs good on WIN32 Console but when I use it in WIN32 Project, ReadDirectoryChangesW doesn't work. It runs and my programming is stopped working.
Help me please, 
Thanks,

Comment: When I run it on WIN32 API Project not Console, my program is stopped working. I cannot turn off it.

Comment: How do you expect to "turn it off"? You have an endless loop in there (most likely not on a separate thread).

Comment: I think it can not stop loop

Comment: @PeterWood what is solution? I don't know how to use timer? Please,

Comment: @VanDerCong I don't know how to user a timer either. I would search first and ask questions later.

Comment: Do you have any solution for my code?

Comment: If you don't have a console, the `wprintf` won't work.  Do you have a console?  Hav eyou tried runnig it under debug?

Comment: my program is break when it calls to ReadDirectoryChangesW function. You should'n worry about it.

Answer (score 1):

Looks like you are blocking the UI thread in win32 project and the application appears to be freezed and it won't respond. Launch a worker thread and do the stuff inside a worker thread.

I think it is better to use notification API's like `SHChangeNotifyRegister` that would let you know if any changes to directory has happened and then you can read the directory instead of doing it in a `while` loop. Also is the application unicode? You are using `ReadDirectoryChangesW`?

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb762120.aspx

Comment: I'm trying to use ReadDirectoryChangesW. Can you give me an example about SHChangeNotifyRegister

Comment: You can read the documentation of `SHChangeNotifyRegister` at msdn. This will help you get notification if something has changes so that you get rid of while loop. Once you get notification you have to probaby do the same thing of read the directory that has changed. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb762120(v=vs.85).aspx          In the documentation they have reference to SDK sample

Comment: I'm using WIN32 API C/C++. Does it works?

Comment: Yes, sample: http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/3226/Using-the-shell-to-receive-notification-of-removab

Comment: Thanks for your time. However I also want to use ReadDirectoryChangesW to watch any change of a directory. I dont know more about SHChangeNotifyRegister. Can you fix my code?

Comment: Create a worker thread `CreateThread` and run the while loop into that thread i.e. the thread function.

Comment: You need to learn how to code a Win32 program which is quite different from a console program. Have a look here: http://www.winprog.org/tutorial/message_loop.html and/or just google for "Win32 message loop".

Comment: Can anyone give me an example about this problem? I don't have more time to solve it?